# Use Windows Azure Worker Role with Celery

Tags: python, django, azure, celery

I have a Web Role in Windows Azure that runs Django. I have a time-consuming calculation to run asynchronously, and the use case is the following: the client sends a request for the calculation, the server returns an ID to check for the calculation result, and then the client can use this ID to retrieve this result as soon as it is out.

Now I am missing the back-end part, and I would like to use a Worker Role in Windows Azure for this. Since I want to stay Azure-independant, I'd like to use Celery to handle this part. The downside is that I could not find any ressource covering this topic. Does anyone have some insights?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider using Windows Azure WebJobs as it supports python scripts: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWindowsAzureWebJobs.aspx

Comment: That seems exactly like what I need! Any thoughts about a more descriptive answer to the "working with Celery" part? (I am currently looking into it but you may be able to have a better insight than I do)

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with celery but if you can make it work on Windows it should work on an Azure role.

Comment: OK maybe you can help on a more general problem then. Celery is installed on my virtualenv that is uploaded along with the Django website. On Windows it works fine but it has to run in a separate bash window. I want to recreate that "separate bash window" usage in Azure, and I think Web Jobs are the best way to do it. I zipped my virtual env along with my Django website (which also contains configuration information for Celery [yes, everything is dupplicated]) but I have an issue when deploying (according to the upload system on Azure I don't have enough disk space, contrary to what the dash

Comment: ...board says). Having to dupplicate everything is not a very nice option either, but I can't seem to be able to change the folder when using WebJobs (eg cd D:/wwwroot does not work). Since the Celery python executable has to be run inside the same folder as the Django application, this is quite an issue.

Answer (score 4):

I did a continuous webjob in azure that runs celery.

```
<your repo>/App_Data/jobs/continuous/Celery/celery.cmd
```

In celery.cmd I start celery like this.

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;D:\home\site\wwwroot\site-packages\
cd D:\home\site\wwwroot\src
DEL D:\home\site\wwwroot\src\celery.pid
D:\Python34\python.exe -m celery -A conf worker -Q celery -c 10 -l DEBUG --pidfile D:\home\site\wwwroot\src\celery.pid
```

So what's happing here is that I set the python path (I'm sure this can be done globally somewere in azure), then I just cd into my project django root and remove any PID file before I run celery command line style. When this process ends, celery will restart again, because it's a continuous webjob.

You might want to tweak the flags to your needs.

If you need to celery to run only on one machine. You have to have a `<your repo>/App_Data/jobs/continuous/Celery/settings.job` file:

```
{"is_singleton": true}
```

Comment: This is quite old but I wanted to update for what worked for me cd D:\home\site\wwwroot
D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Scripts\python.exe -m celery -A yourapp.celery worker --loglevel=info --concurrency=1

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would make it a bit more clear on what to do, to get the celery worker started on the web app:
 1. Create a file called celery.cmd and add the following contents:

```
cd D:\home\site\wwwroot 
D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Scripts\python.exe -m celery -A yourapp.celery worker --loglevel=info --concurrency=1
```

2. Create a file called settings.job with the following content (this ensures that if the web app scales, the worker doesn't scale as well):

```
{"is_singleton": true}
```

3.Zip the 2 above files

4.In the Azure portal, create a **continuous** web job and upload the zip file along with it.